# WPF grid row height doesn't match the height that I input

Tags: wpf, grid, height

I've been pulling my hair out all day on this.  For some reason when I set up my grid while I'm using some custom controls the actual height of the grid rows changes around and doesn't bother to use the height values that I give it.  I originally thought it was because I was loading in custom controls in the code, but even when I take the custom controls out the problem remains.  Here's what I have for the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Pokemon_Planner.PokePlan"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="PokePlan" Height="600" Width="800">
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25" Name="row0"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" Name="row1"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="48" Name="row2"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
        <ComboBox Name="cmbSort" Width="100">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Name"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Type"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Element"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="BP"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Min Damage"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Max Damage"></ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Name="btnSort" Click="btnSort_Click">Sort</Button>
        <Button Name="btnRefresh" Click="btnRefresh_Click">Refresh</Button>
        <Button Name="btnFilter">Filter</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="stkMoveSet1">

    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal" Name="stkMoveSet2">

    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="6" Height="Auto" Name="scrollViewerMoves" >
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="6" Name="moveStackPanel"></StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The row that was set to have a height of 48 still had that height set, but the 'actual height' was 446 which is still really screwing my grid up.  The numbers vary and I've tried a lot of different combinations between set numbers and auto but I can't seem to get this one window to behave correctly.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to change "row2" grid row height definition to "auto" and set height to 48 for the "scrollViewerMoves" scrollviewer. Smth like this:

```
...
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="row2"></RowDefinition>
...
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height = "48" Name="scrollViewerMoves" >
...
```

I guess this should do what you need, 
regards

Comment: Thank you very much, Serge.  That got me on the right way. The scrollviewer isn't on row 2, so I changed the stackpanels on rows 2 and 3 and it worked beautifully!  The problem now seems to be the scrollviewer, since it's making row 1 huge now that the others are under control.  I tried changing it's size, which didn't do much, then I got rid of the rowspan and things lined up correctly.  Except for the scrollviewer itself.

I want the scrollviewer selection to span from row1 to the bottom of the screen, but without rowspan it's invisible when row2 starts.  Are there any work arounds for this?

Comment: I guess putting scrollviewer's height back to "auto" should get it spanned across rows, I guess smth like this:

..ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="6" Height="Auto"..

Comment: it has to work on windows and works fine for me; there are could be problems with parsing pdf files but ususally you get an error message from gs with an explanation of what is missing or broken; can you post up your pdf file somewere on file sharing service so I could try converting it

Comment: Oddly enough, removing Height="Auto" and just leaving it blank took care of the problem.  Thank you and Happy (Holiday of your choice)!

Comment: thnx, I guess having nested grids might do what you need